# isotope Masonry not vertically stacking variable height items properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, jquery-isotope

Could someone explain what am i doing wrong as this masonry layout from isotope plugin is not working correctly for me. Why are the items behaving like they are in a row instead of stacking masonry style?

http://jsbin.com/vaposovuwo/edit?html,css,js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="grid">

    <div class="grid-item">
      <h3>Hello how are you fdgdfg dfgdf gdf gdjadfhg dfga fgaf gad </h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto facilis fuga asperiores, eos, nam numquam illum placeat, cumque minus nihil, repellendus. Blanditiis quia similique architecto, obcaecati inventore magnam cupiditate molestias.</p>
    </div> <!-- grid item -->

    <div class="grid-item">
      <h3>Hello how are you</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dsf sdfs df sdfsdfsdfs dfsdfsdf sdfs d fsdolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto facilis fuga asperiores, eos, nam numquam illum placeat, cumque minus nihil, repellendus. Blanditiis quia similique architecto, obcaecati inventore magnam cupiditate molestias.</p>
    </div> <!-- grid item -->

    <div class="grid-item">
      <h3>Hello how are you</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit adsfsd dsfsd met, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto facilis fuga asperiores, eos, nam numquam illum placeat, cumque minus nihil, repellendus. Blanditiis quia similique architecto, obcaecati inventore magnam cupiditate molestias.</p>
    </div> <!-- grid item -->

    <div class="grid-item">
      <h3>Hello how asdf sdf sdf sdhgdtjhdghgdf fgd fre you</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cons fdag adfag fda gadfgadf gadfg adf gadgad gadgad gad gagadf ectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto facilis fuga asperiores, eos, nam numquam illum placeat, cumque minus nihil, repellendus. Blanditiis quia similique architecto, obcaecati inventore magnam cupiditate molestias.</p>
    </div> <!-- grid item -->

    <div class="grid-item">
      <h3>Hello how are you</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto facilis fuga asperiores, eos, nam numquam illum placeat, cumque minus nihil, repellendus. Blanditiis quia similique architecto, obcaecati inventore magnam cupiditate molestias.</p>
    </div> <!-- grid item -->

    <div class="grid-item">
      <h3>Hello how are df gdf gdfhjtrhtrtrt hrhrt hrt rtyyou</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto facilis fuga asperiores, eos, nam numquam illum placeat, cumque minus nihil, repellendus. Blanditiis quia similique architecto, obcaecati inventore magnam cupiditate molestias.</p>
    </div> <!-- grid item -->

    <div class="grid-item">
      <h3>Hello how are you</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto facilis fuga asperiores, eos, nam numquam illum placeat, cumque minus nihil, repellendus. Blanditiis quia similique architecto, obcaecati inventore magnam cupiditate molestias.</p>
    </div> <!-- grid item -->
  </div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.grid-item {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: tomato;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
  float: left;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.grid').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Most importantly is that your jsbin does not have jQuery loaded and you are also adding isotope.js twice as well as trying to add fit-columns.js but it's not in a script tag.

This is what you have:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
//npmcdn.com/isotope-fit-columns@1/fit-columns.js
```

This is what you need to have:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://npmcdn.com/isotope-fit-columns@1/fit-columns.js"></script>
```